# How to push nupkg file to Azure DevOps feed?

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, azure-artifacts, private-nuget-feed

I have .nupkg file that I would like to add to the feed I've created in Azure DevOps. The feed is called `Feed`. Unfortunately, the only way I see right now is to polute the repo by pushing the file by Git and then creating a release definition that pushes it into the correct feed.
Like here:

[image]

Can I somehow upload `.nupkg` file directly from my drive? I don't have source code for the file, I won't build it.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish the `.npukg` from your drive with the command line, you just need to `nuget.exe` installed (if you have Visual Studio so you have it).

1) Add the feed as a source:

```
nuget.exe sources Add -Name "FeedName" -Source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_packaging/NugetTest/nuget/v3/index.json"
```

2) Push the file to the feed:

```
nuget.exe push -Source "FeedName" -ApiKey az <packagePath> (e.g. C:/test.nupkg)
```

Comment: I got `Your package was pushed` message, but I can't see it in Azure DevOps is there a way to see available packages? There was 2 years ago, but I can't find it now.

Comment: How have you came up with `"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_packaging/NugetTest/nuget/v3/index.json"` json at the end? I've just cut url from browser when I connected to feed in it. I suspect this is not the way, however I got no errors in command line. `16111ms
Your package was pushed.`

Comment: When I tried to go this way `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_packaging/{feedName}/nuget/v3/index.json` I got  `NuGet.Protocol.Plugins.ProtocolException: An error occurred while sending the request.`

Comment: I also tried from Package Manager Console: `dotnet nuget push --source "feedname" --api-key az "packagefile"` but I got  `Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).` with no popup for credentials or sth similar

Comment: Check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops#get-your-feeds-nuget-package-source-information and here https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#azure-artifacts-credential-provider